# Jquery Check if class name contains character e.g. "Y" or "N"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say that you have a loop and depending on the outcome of the loop you add a class name to DIV, either Y or N. Based on Y or N you want to change the css properties of that class. See code below:

```
function percentageCount() {

    $(".Parent").children().each(function(i, valOuter) { // Outer Loop
        alert("Outer loop");
        alert($(valOuter).html());
        var totalPercentage = 0;
        $(valOuter).children().find(':input').each(function(ii, valInner) { // Inner Loop        
            //                alert("Inner loop");


            totalPercentage += parseInt(this.value);
            //                alert("total percentage: " + totalPercentage);

            if (this.value == '') {
                totalPercentage += 0; // Assume empty string == 0
            }

            if (totalPercentage == 100) {
                alert("Percentage equals to 100");
                $(valOuter).removeClass("N");
                $(valOuter).addClass("Y");
            }

            else {
                alert("Percentage must equal to 100");
                $(valOuter).removeClass("Y");
                $(valOuter).addClass("N");

            }
        }); // Inner Loop
    });      // Outer Loop

    // Code to search for JQuery class

    });
```

What would be a good way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by changing the CSS properties of the class?

Comment: @Jack. That's the only part I understood in the question... Maybe you can explain me the rest?

Comment: What I meant is I want to change the CSS based on class name. So if there is .N then background colour red for No etc.

Comment: @nickgowdy but you don't need jQuery for that? Just make CSS definitions for `.Y` and `.N`

Comment: @gdoron yes I reckon this is  what OP asked I reckon ++! `Based on Y or N you want to change the css properties of that class`

Comment: Yea you are right but since I have the answer I am going to include it as part of my javascript/jquery logic. This code is part of a user control which is used many times on one page so this is how I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.Y') // Will give you all the Y class elements
$('.N') // Will give you all the N class elements
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I was expecting it be more difficult because the exact class name is .Percentage0 N or .Percentage10 Y depending on loops in the code. I was expecting to be more explicit with my Jquery selector but I was wrong.

Comment: @nickgowdy. `$('.className')` will select every element with that class, no only it's the only class name it has.

Comment: Yea I know that now I don't use jquery much so I guess I learnt something new. Thanks anyway.